# How to allow different data formats in Azure table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an azure table and queue created and I have code that will take the messages in the queue and insert it into the table. The code works but how do I account for different data entries? For eg. ID:Name:Age:Vaccinated is the main input but a user inputs Name:Age:ID:Vaccinated.

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {

            try
            {
                bool isVac = false;
                log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

                // Gets the ID from the myQueueItem 
                string ID = myQueueItem.Substring(0, myQueueItem.IndexOf(getString));
                log.LogInformation($"ID: {ID}");

                myQueueItem = getNewString(myQueueItem);
                log.LogInformation($"New String: {myQueueItem}");

                string name = myQueueItem.Substring(0, myQueueItem.IndexOf(getString));
                log.LogInformation($"Name: {name}");

                myQueueItem = getNewString(myQueueItem);
                log.LogInformation($"New String: {myQueueItem}");

                string age = myQueueItem;
                log.LogInformation($"Age: {age}");

                // Gets the vaccination status from the myQueueItem
                string vac = myQueueItem.Substring(0, myQueueItem.IndexOf(getString));
                log.LogInformation($"Vac: {vac}");
                if (vac.ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                {
                    isVac = true;
                }

                AddToTable(ID, name, int.Parse(age), isVac);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                log.LogInformation(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

```
        private void AddToTable(string ID, string name, int age, bool isVac)
        {
            string connectionString ="";
            TableClient tableClient = new TableClient(connectionString, "Vac");
            tableClient.CreateIfNotExists();

            var entity = new Person()
            {
                PartitionKey = "South Africa",
                RowKey = ID,
                Name = name,
                Age = age,
                Vacinated = isVac
            };
            tableClient.AddEntity(entity);
        }
```

I tried a method to get each value from the string and reformat it but I had no luck on that (I don't have the code anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass a json as the message content. Then, once you deserialize it, it doesn't matter the order as long as the name of the properties remain the same.

```
public class Person
{
    public string PartitionKey => "South Africa";

    [JsonProperty("rowKey")]
    public string RowKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vacinated")]
    public bool Vacinated { get; set; }
}

[FunctionName("Function1")]
public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{

    try
    {
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(myQueueItem);

        AddToTable(model);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

        log.LogInformation(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void AddToTable(Person model)
{
    string connectionString ="";
    TableClient tableClient = new TableClient(connectionString, "Vac");
    tableClient.CreateIfNotExists();
    
    tableClient.AddEntity(model);
}
```